# Checking Wordpress core files

Tags: wordpress

Is there a script or something that can check if all core files are installed properly. I am installing a Wordpress site on clients hosting, and for some reason around 100 files were not transferred due to the connection time out. Now I am moving them one by one, but still I would like to check somehow, once I am done, that all files transferred are there and their size is more than 0b.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you transferring them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Filezilla, drag and drop all files again into the folder.

Then when the file exists message shows up, pick `Overwrite if different size` and check `apply to current queue only`. Then only the ones with different sizes (or the ones that weren't transferred) will be overwritten/updated.

**There's an easier way:**

If you have access to some kind of control panel like cPanel, you can make a .zip file and upload it only via Filezilla.

Then on cPanel, go to File Explorer and unzip from there. Will be faster and you just have to upload one file (rather than opening tons of connections and giving you timeout).

Or if you have shell access, you can login with your key using Terminal(mac) or Putty(win), browse the folder and run the `unzip` command.

Comment: Thanks, will do as you suggested

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić I had this problem when uploading a folder with more han 500 images. Since it's one connection per file, ftp clients tends to sometimes "forget" to close that connection and then, server return 'too many connections' error or simply 'timeout' when there are too many. It's a lot faster to upload one single big file and then let server handle the unzip. Let me know if you got any other questions :)